# MongooseAutoIncrementID.initialise is not a function.." is being displayed if i use ES5 require ('mongoose-auto-increment-reworked')

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-5

I am trying to use [mongoose-auto-increment-reworked](https://github.com/Alorel/mongoose-auto-increment-reworked) package, but in its setup it shows ES6's ( import -- from "--" ) method to import package, but due to rest of the my app i'm forced to use require method e.g.

```
const MongooseAutoIncrementID = require ('mongoose-auto-increment-reworked');
```

It gives the following error: TypeError: MongooseAutoIncrementID.initialise is not a function..

when i try

```
MongooseAutoIncrementID.initialise('productIncrement');
```

and the error: TypeError: MongooseAutoIncrementID is not a constructor

when i try

```
const plugin = new MongooseAutoIncrementID(ProductItemSchema, 'ProductItem',options);
```

Can anyone tell, how can i make this work?
or do i have to rewrite entire backend according to ES6.

Comment: for anyone else, question remains unanswered, however i was able to use slightly older package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment-fix.

Comment: Can you use a transpiler such as babel to convert this to ES5?

Comment: hey! saw that suggestion in some post too! but i was little afraid how rest of the app (backend) would react to babel, thats why i didnt give it a try!

Comment: It shouldn't cause any conflicts. I'm having to transpile ES6 code to ES5 to support legacy IE browsers. It takes longer to compile but it just converts to vanilla javascript. Worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

According to an answer on another forum, this package/library does not have `module.exports` hence `require()` cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You must import it like this:

```
const { MongooseAutoIncrementID } = require('mongoose-auto-increment-reworked')
```

Since `MongooseAutoIncrementID` is a function you need to access it by destructuring assignment ([see how destructuring works in JavaScript](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/))

You can also import it without destructuring by accessing to the package function directly:

```
const MongooseAutoIncrementID = require('mongoose-auto-increment-reworked').MongooseAutoIncrementID
```

Both methods will work.